# In Vuetify, how to prevent a checked v-checkbox from being deselected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js

I have a checkbox:

```
<v-checkbox
     v-for="company in allCompanies" :key="`company_${company.id}`"
     :label="company.name"
     :value="company.id"
     v-model="selectedCompanies"
/>
```

How could I prevent a selected box from being deselected without having to resort to using radio buttons?

Or how to, using Javascript, check whether a specific checkbox has been deselected?

Comment: Would it be possible to disable it? There's a prop called `disabled`.

Comment: It would be possible to disable a checkbox but that also prevents the users from selecting - selecting is fine but I just want to prevent deselecting

Comment: Why would you allow them to select but not deselect? :/

Comment: @change="disableThisCBForSuperWeirdBehaviour=$event"

Comment: @Beginner_Hello Regardless of the why, you could either disable or set it to `readonly` once selected.

Comment: Yom: That sounds like a great idea! How would I be able to set to to readonly on select?

Comment: I suppose you can add the checkbox without any property and once it is clicked you call a method which makes the checkbox disabled but selected

Comment: @Beginner_Hello You should be able to toggle the `readonly` state from within the `change` event of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working codepen
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/dyYERzX

Template part:

```
<div id="app">
 <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-container fluid>
     <v-layout row wrap>
       <v-flex xs12 md6>
         <v-subheader>Checkbox</v-subheader>
          <v-card flat>
           <v-card-text>
             <v-checkbox :disabled="disabled" v-bind:label="`Checkbox 1:    ${ex1.toString()}`" v-model="ex1" light @ @change="hehe"></v-checkbox>             
              </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Script part:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data () {
return {
  ex1: false,
  disabled:false,
}
  },
 methods:{
hehe(){
  console.log("hehe")
this.disabled=true;
    }
  }
})
```